# Programmability - I want to add all the del lines together to make a total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have some code that pulls the cost of a delivery line (del). I want to know if it is possible to get this code to return the total cost of the all the (del) lines as the packing slip may have more than one delivery line in the shipment.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUnitPrice](@strPackNum NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UnitPrice DECIMAL(10,2)
    SET @UnitPrice = 0

    SELECT @UnitPrice = od.UnitPrice 
    FROM OrderDtl OD 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ShipDtl SD ON od.OrderNum = sd.OrderNum 
                               AND od.Company = sd.Company 
    WHERE 
        od.PartNum = 'DEL' 
        AND sd.PartNum = 'DEL'
        AND sd.PackNum = @strPackNum

    RETURN @UnitPrice
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `sum` the prices:

```sql
select @UnitPrice=SUM(od.UnitPrice) 
from OrderDtl OD 
left outer join ShipDtl SD on od.OrderNum = sd.OrderNum and od.Company = sd.Company 
where od.PartNum = 'DEL' and sd.PartNum = 'DEL' and sd.PackNum = @strPackNum
```